# Macro: Filter, Copy and Paste Special

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am running into issues with the Paste Special part of the following code

```
Sub Copy_Filter1()

    Sheets("MASTER PLACEMENT").Select
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("MASTER PLACEMENT").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
Selection.AutoFilter Field:=52, Criteria1:=">=104"

Columns("AG:AS").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Hidden = True

If (Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row <= LastRow) Then
    Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

[`PasteSpecial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx) is a method of the `Range` object, not the `Worksheet` object (which is where you are currently using it).

For example, your call should look like:

```
' Paste the current clipboard contents to cell B2 on Sheet1.
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like below

```
Sub Copy_Filter1()


    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000").Select
    Dim LastRow As Long
            LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter
            Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=104"


    If (Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row <= LastRow) Then
        Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

    End If
```

End Sub